# JSON error in Ionic due to header in Laravel response

Tags: json, ionic-framework, laravel-8

I have been following the tutorial in https://medium.com/@flicher/laravel-rest-api-passport-authentication-for-ionic-app-3934713bcdf7 but having some trouble with the response when testing registration..

Registration is successful and the expected response by the ionic APP is JSON but the laravel response contains headers as well as JSON and returns as

```
<!-- CSRF Token -->
<!--
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="{{ asset('vendor/file-manager/js/file-manager.js') }}"></script>
-->
{"message":"Successfully created user!"}
```

Giving me the HttpResponseError

```
Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1
```

despite the registration being successful

Answer (score 1):

Edited the options section of the post request to recieve response as text not JSON.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).